# Is it possible to set the width of an input element dynamically using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, input, width

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b56Fd/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    abc
    <input />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width:80%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
input {
    width:90%;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a pure CSS way to modify an input element width, adjusting to the available space left.

Thanks.

Comment: "links to jsfiddle.org must be accompanied by code"

Comment: I added code and JSFiddle from the link he partially gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a pure CSS solution, you could wrap around the `<input>` by a container `<div>` and hide the horizontal overflow of the box with `overflow-x: hidden;`.

Then float the text to the left, using a `<label>` element:

HTML:

```html
<label>abc</label>
<div class="wrapper">
    <input />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.wrapper { overflow-x: hidden; }
label { float: left; }
input { width:100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/b56Fd/5/)**